# solr sunpost interaction between two application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot-solr

I have developed an application with rails and solr sunspot full text search.

Here users can post a topic. And the user need to wait for approval of the post from the administrator.

Eg: If a user post a topic in `domain.com` and the approval is made from `admin.domain.com`

```
@search = Post.where(status: 1).search do
      fulltext params[:search] do
        minimum_match 1
      end
      with :status, 1
      paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 15
    end
    @posts = @search.results
```

Unless admin approve the post status will be `2`. In administrator if I change the status from 2 to 1 from admin I could not find the result. How can I interlink with it.

How can I handle this kind of problem. Can any one help

**Edit-1**

I am going to make this as a bounty question. I am facing lot of difficulty with this. Can any one solve this with better solution else anyone know any other way of performing such a search

Comment: It's like your post object has not been indexed after update with admin. Do you use 2 applications : your main app and and admin app ?

Comment: Yes I have two app how can I update it

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 applications, I presume they used same database but only your main app use sunspot.

The problem is when an admin update an object this object is not reindexed in sunspot/solr.

**Option 1**
Add sunspot on your admin app with same searchable block for concerned models, and used same solr server configuration.

**Option 2**
Create a custom controller method ( like an api ) on your main app. This method forces reindex of an object like `Sunspot.index Post.find(params[:id])`
After each update on a Post on your admin app, you need to call reindex post method of your main app.

**Option 3** (easiest)
Remove your scope on :status like this :

```
@search = Post.where(status: 1).search do
  fulltext params[:search] do
    minimum_match 1
  end
  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 15
end
@posts = @search.results
```

**Edit**

This update add more informations for use option 1 :

I create an application with one model : Article

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :content
    integer :status
  end
end
```

I want to show all articles on my admin app and only articles with status=1 on my user app. Both applications use same database and same solr server.

**Configuration for both applications**

I use sunspot_rails(https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) and sunspot_solr for this test.

```
#Gemfile 
gem 'sunspot_rails'

group :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end

#config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

#config/sunspot.yml use same host and same port for both applications
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development
```

**Note** : I launch solr only one time on user app with this command

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

**Article controller for admin app**

I want to show all articles on my admin app like this :

```
def index
  @search = Article.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @articles = @search.results
end
```

**Article controller for user app**

In my user app, I just want to see articles with statuts == 1

```
def index
  @search = Article.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    with :status,1
  end
  @articles = @search.results
end
```

Now when I use my admin app, and I update an article's status solr is updated simultaneously.
And if I refresh my articles index page on my main app, this article appears.

I hope you have more informations now.

Comment: How can I share same solr for two application.

Comment: @Seting Add same solr gem that you used in your main app, with same configuration (host of your solr sever specify in you main app - port ) and copy your Post searchable block ( that exists in your main model ) into your Post admin model. I think it's the hardest way to solve your problem. Before try to use same solr server with 2 rails app, try option 3 and remove `with :status, 1`

Comment: @Seting Its no problem to access the same solr server from two apps, because your interacting with it through http.

Comment: @Seting : edit my answer with more infos about option 1